# Express: завернуть логику аутентификации в middleware

Tags: node.js, express, auth, рефакторинг

Не могу разобраться, как правильно представить данную логику (через middleware) в express.js? И верна ли вообще такая логика аутентификации?

UPD. Не имею в виду эту строку `if (user.username === 'user' && user.password === '123')`, тут будет проверка через базу

```js
function isAuthenticated(req) {
  const user = req.session.user
  if (user && user.isAuthenticated) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  if (isAuthenticated(req)) {
    res.redirect('/admin')
  } else {
    res.render('login.jade')
  }
});
app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.session.destroy();
  res.redirect('/login');
});
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  var user = {
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password,
    isAuthenticated: false
  }
  if (user.username === 'user' && user.password === '123') {
    user.isAuthenticated = true;
    req.session.user = user;
    res.redirect('/admin');
  } else {
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
});
app.all('/admin', (req, res)=>{
  if (isAuthenticated(req)) {
    res.render('admin.jade');
  } else {
    res.redirect('/login')
  }
});
```

Comment: ```const response: Response = await fetch(request)
  return response```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В `app.post('/login')` получаем в `body` login + password, проверяем данные по базе, если ок, то создаем сессию для пользователя, иначе отправляем ошибку.

```
let u = ... // полученные данных из модели по login + password
if (!u)
    return next(new Error('BAD_USERPASS'));

req.session.user = u;
res.status(200).send(u.name);
```

---

```
// middlewares/user.js
exports.user = function(req, res, next) {
    req.user = res.locals.user = null;

    // Check session
    if (!req.session || !req.session.user || !req.session.user.id)
        return next();

    var u = ... // Данные из модели, напр по req.session.user.id; 
    req.user = res.locals.user = (!!u && !!u.id) ? u : null;
    next(); // После выполнения в req.locals.user будут данные о пользователе
}
app.use('middlewares/user');
```

---

```
// middlewares/auth.js 
exports.auth = function(req, res, next) {
    // Проверяем, что пользователь задан или имеет доступ.
    return next(new Error((req.user) ? 403 : 401));
}
// Если надо проверять не все роуты
var auth = require('middlewares/auth');
app.get('/smth-path', auth, function(req, res, next) { ...render...});
// Если надо проверять все роуты
app.use('middlewares/auth');
```

Comment: это я понимаю, вопрос в том, как не вызвать бесконечный редирект на роуте `logout`

Comment: Откуда бесконечный редирект возьмется?

Comment: прошу прощения, попутал, разобрался с вашей помощью, спасибо!